# Spring batch 2.1.8 Run a single instance of a job, when a quartz cron trigger fires

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I have a spring batch quartz set up. I have two jobs configured and running in parallel. The jobs are reading a file and then writing some data to the db. Here is the tricky part, the file names are calculated within the beforeJob() method of my execution listener. After each job finishes, the afterJob() would then calculate the next fileName. File names have the following pattern `xxxxxx.nnnn` where nn.. are numbers and sometimes the sequence can have numbers missing, therefore I am attempting "jump" over those missing passages and when I find an existing number to launch the job.
I want to know if it's possible to restrict the number of jobs launched each time the cron trigger fires? I want to have a single job launched after a chron trigger fires.

For example:

1. At 12.30 PM the job is launched.
2. The job tries to find the correct file
3. The job fails with FileNotFound ( which is configured as a non -skippable exception)
4. After the job, the fileName counter is incremented

Right now, when the trigger fires, I get like 4 or more jobs of the same type being executed asynchronously. In my batch set-up I have two `<jobs>` configured to launch one after the other each hour within a 5 minutes interval of one another. The jobs both fallow the flow provided in the example. In conclusion : Is it possible to launch a single job after a cron trigger fires and have both job types run in parallel.

Peter

Comment: In simple case you can configure your `taskExecutor` for your `jobLauncher` to accept only one job at a time.

Comment: Is there a way to terminate the batch after a successful job instance execution ?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can tell Spring Batch to terminate after one batch is processed (configured by `commit-interval`) by updating the job executions status: `jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPING); jobRepository.update(jobExecution);`. Spring Batch will reload the status in next iteration and gracefully terminate. Alternatively you can throw an exception.

Comment: That didn't work, Within my `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` I've updated the state of the batch and I get this `JOB[33505] finished with status STOPPING and exitStatusexitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription= `. Which is what I wanted I guess but a new job is being launched afterwards. By the way about the `commit-interval` the only tag that has that property is the `<chunk>`, or am I missing something obvious, which is not that unlikely :)

Comment: I think I've misinterpreted your question. For me it sounded like "Is there a way to terminate the batch after job has successfully started". What you really asked is "Is there a way to terminate the batch after job has finished" and that is what you tried to do in `afterJob()`. I think your intention does not have any sense. Maybe what you need is review how you create `JobParameters`? Provide a relevant code. I suppose what you do: you scan for new files in job. That is not quite correct. You need to scan for new files before launching a lob and pass the file name as parameter.

Comment: Yes that is what I was doing. My ItemReaders need the fileName so is there a way to provide the file name to them (basicly have access to the jobParameters ) ? Right now I am using the ExecutionListener and I hate my self for doing it, but I just couldn't figure any other way of passing the fileName.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your job should know what file to process before it is executed. E.g. the file name should be passed as job parameter. Remove `JobExecutionListener` and add `StepExecutionListener` to access job parameters via `StepExecution#getJobParameters()`. One job = one file.

Now from your scheduler you want to make sure that only one job is run at one point of time. You can achieve this in two ways:

• Using the async task executor. In this case each time you launch the job, it will not be executed in a background (unless your scheduler does not fire timer events each time in new thread).

```
<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
```

• If you use the same job launcher for other jobs, which need to be executed in background, you need to use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` but you can manually check if the job is running:

```
for (final JobInstance jobInstance : jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName(), 0, LOOK_BEHIND_INSTANCES)) {
    for (final JobExecution jobExecution : jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance)) {
        final BatchStatus status = jobExecution.getStatus();

        if (status.isRunning()) {
            // Ops:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks that actually really helped. The problem was org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean I just set it to use a single thread and it worked, plus I took your advice and started using the jobParams.

Comment: It would be surprising that Quartz is firing events in one thread only :) I am happy you've found the solution. Enjoy batching :)