# How could I guarantee that only one JobInstance of a job run at the same time?

Tags: spring-batch

Spring Batch documentation says: "*Spring Batch will make no attempt to stop them from being run concurrently*" (http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html).

But I would like to get an error if I try to run a job and there is an instance of that job running. Is it possible?

I am using Spring Batch 2.1.8.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you asked for, but you can ensure that only one job is running at a time by setting using an executor with a pool-size attribute of 1.  That will cause the jobs to queue up, with only one running at a time.

Answer (score 5):

If you're aware that subsequent job will be queued up, you can use TaskExecutor.

1. Instantiate a task executor with maximum pool size, say 500

   ```
   <task:executor id="poolTaskExecutor" pool-size="500"/>
   ```
2. ThrottledTaskexecutor

   ThrottledTaskExecutor will pass only given number of tasks at a time to above *poolTaskExecutor*. 
   This class can be found below in spring github, or you can download maven artifact.
   https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/util/ThrottledTaskExecutor.java
3. Instantiate ThrottledTaskExecutor

   ```
   <bean id="throttledTaskExecutor" 
         class="org.springframework.batch.admin.util.ThrottledTaskExecutor">
     <property name="taskExecutor" ref="poolTaskExecutor" />
     <property name="throttleLimit" value="1"/>
   </bean>
   ```
4. ThrottledJobLauncher

   ```
   <bean id="throttledJobLauncher"
           class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
       <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
       <property name="taskExecutor" ref="throttledTaskExecutor" />
   </bean>
   ```

All jobs launched using *throttledJobLauncher* above will be running only one instance at a time. This is more flexible that you can limit one or multiple jobs with given throttledLimit.

Actually above poolTaskExecutor definition and ThrottledTaskexecutor class is from spring-batch-admin. These are out-of-box feature. You just have to define ThrottledTaskExecutor with limit and include in the jobLauncher of your job.

Answer (score 2):

You could check

```
jobExecution.getStatus()
```

as described in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8711857/1627688